# For positive $a$, $b$, $c$ with $a+b+c=1$, show that $(ab+bc+ca) \sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b^2+b} \geq \frac34$

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c > 0$ and $a+b+c = 1$, then prove that
>   $$\left(\frac{a}{b^2+b}+\frac{b}{c^2+c}+\frac{c}{a^2+a}\right)(ab+bc+ca)\geq\frac{3}{4}$$

It's been more than 35 years since I last touched algebra!!

Comment: How did this problem arise? It looks like a contest problem ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber no idea :) A friend gave it to me, challenging me to solve it. I don't know what to do, other than starting multiplications etc - I assume at some point I must use cauchy, but I don't even remember these things, sorry!

Comment: i've tried partial fractions and the $(a+b+c)^2 $ identity .  All to no avail...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Using generalised Holder’s inequality
$$\sum_{cyc}ab \cdot \sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{b^2+b}\cdot \sum_{cyc} a(b+1) \geqslant \left(\sum_{cyc}a\right)^3=1$$

Now it is enough to show $\sum_{cyc} a(b+1) \leqslant \frac43$ which is easy.

Comment: Do you mean $a(b+1)$ or $\frac{b+1}{a}$?

Comment: @EuxhenH The former - exactly as written.